# Solr Replication - count on files downloaded from master

Tags: solr, replication

[Solr Replication](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrReplication#How_does_the_slave_replicate.3F)

Can we count no. of files downloaded in current replication process.

Comment: Did you look at admin page? http://localhost:8983/solr/#/collection1/replication

Comment: @Arun Yes, there is nothing information like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the replication details command API (URL: http://example.com:8983/solr/replication?command=details&wt=json&json.nl=map)

The file list of the last (or current) commit is under: details.commits.filelist